# How validation laravel array validation and display message with input field

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

1. How validate and display validate message in small tag

```
<div class="checkbox">
      @foreach($permissions as $permission)
          <li><input type="checkbox" value="{{ $permission->id }}" name="permissions[]" class="flat"> {{ $permission->name }}</li>
      @endforeach
 </div>
<small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('permissions[]') }}</small>
```

controller Code

```
 'permissions' => 'required',
```

Comment: `$errors->first('permissions[]')` should be `$errors->first('permissions')` (you don't use `[]` to reference errors with an array input).

Comment: $errors->first('permissions') not work 
i want to show message

Comment: That code will show an error if there actually is one... Did you submit your form?

Comment: Everything is ok but permission field validation message not display

Answer (score 0):

If you are using newer version of Laravel as you tagged it, then just do the following:

```
@error('permissions')
    <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
@enderror
```

If not then:

```
@if($errors->has('permissions'))
    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('permissions') }}</small>
@endif
```

And if you want to validate each item of the array, you need to change your code to this:

```
'permissions.*' => 'required',
```

Comment: @TimLewis that's the reason why I said if he wants to validate **each item** of the array.

Comment: Yup, didn't see that (or you edited it after the fact)

Comment: @TanbeerHasan then accepting an answer that worked will help others :)

Answer (score 0):

I use almost below code and recommend you like this

```
<small class="text-danger">{{$errors->has('permissions') ? $errors->first('permissions') : ''}}</small>
```

Comment: @TanbeerHasan my pleasure